# Installing Camel K on Kubernetes via helm produces error

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I am new to Kubernetes, Docker and containerization (yes I am late) but I currently want to be able to deploy a Camelet and a Camel-K integration on an already existing Kubernetes cluster. Locally I run with Docker Desktop and I configured it like described on the Apache Camel Homepage.

Unfortunately I cannot install the "kamel" CLI tool because the company settings are not allowing it, so I have to execute every by myself.

Therefore I did what is described on this homepage:
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/camel-k/camel-k#configuration

and added the repo which seemed to work, but when I execute the following command:

```
helm install \
  --generate-name \
  --set platform.build.registry.address=${REGISTRY_ADDRESS} \
  --set platform.build.registry.insecure=true \
  camel-k/camel-k
```

I get the error `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: camel-k/templates/NOTES.txt:5:221: executing "camel-k/templates/NOTES.txt" at <0>: wrong type for value; expected string; got int64`

and now I have no clue what I did wrong.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `REGISTRY_ADDRESS` variable. Helm is expecting a `string` value. But you are providing value of type `int64`.

So, Please double check the value that you have configured in `REGISTRY_ADDRESS` variable.

```
helm install \
--generate-name \
--set platform.build.registry.address=docker.io \
--set platform.build.registry.insecure=true \
camel-k/camel-k
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information at hand, it looks like a mismatch error with the data types as REGISTRY_ADDRESS is being interpreted as a different data type rather than a string. You might need to verify the configuration of your helm. You can start by checking the Camel K Helm chart as it may pose a compatibility issue with kubernetes if the version mismatch. Attached is the documentation for Apache Camel K for your reference.[1]

[1] https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/2.0.x/

Answer (score 0):

Likely you're not following the entire procedure in https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/camel-k/camel-k

The example provided is if you're using Minikube, so, before performing the installation procedure, you need to run:

```
$ minikube addons enable registry
$ export REGISTRY_ADDRESS=$(kubectl -n kube-system get service registry -o jsonpath='{.spec.clusterIP}')
```

Then, as mentioned in other answers, you need to verify that the value in the REGISTRY_ADDRESS variable is the one expected (it should be on Minikube something like `1.2.3.4`).

In general, if you need to configure a different kind of registry, feel free to have a look at the [official documentation](https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/next/installation/registry/registry.html).